# Automation script for Minimal Form Interface with dynamic ids

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to automate a minimal form interface using Selenium to capture an element & later Java code.

But the challenge is the minimal form has only one input container which is constantly changing and the input container generates dynamic id's so finding the element by id name is not possible.

The input container cannot be mapped with xpath because xpath also uses the id 
eg. //md-select[@id='select_15'].

Comment: Please provide HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath for your selection `//md-select[contains(@id,'select')]`

- Contains function use for finding containing values. [Refer This](http://www.abodeqa.com/2013/01/29/contains-and-starts-with-function-in-xpath/)

Let me know If any query.